# Debug in WP backend

Tags: plugins, headers, callbacks, warnings

The problem - I get these warnings each time I login to /admin page in WP.
Depending on which browser I use, there are problems with these:

> Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'add_role_caps_to_job_agent' not found or invalid function name in /var/www/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 298
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /var/www/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php:298) in /var/www//public_html/wp-includes/option.php on line 837
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /var/www/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php:298) in /var/www/public_html/wp-includes/option.php on line 838

I've tried to look into `option.php` and `class-wp.-hook.php` but I've not much experience or knowledge what to look for.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

The warning states the issue is coming from custom code as in core WP no function as `add_role_caps_to_job_agent` exists. Try searching for `add_role_caps_to_job_agent` in `wp-content`, to see how this function is getting called and fix or uncomment the call.

The other two notices will disappear once the first notice is solved as WP is trying to set/send headers which is possible only, if nothing was printed to the screen before.

Comment: Do I need to go through all plugins/theme etc. to find this debug?

Comment: Simply open your project codebase in an editor and search for the string…